# Real Analysis, Folland Proposition 3.11 The Radon Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Proposition 3.11: If $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ are measures on $(X,M)$, there is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_j\ll\mu$ for all $j$ -- namely $\mu = \sum_1^n\mu_j$.

Attempted proof: Suppose we have a sequence of measures $\{\mu_j\}_1^n$ on $(X,M)$. Then for any measurable set $E$ suppose $\mu_j(E) = 0$. Then define $$\mu = \sum_1^n \mu_j$$ then clearly $\mu(E) = 0$ then $\mu_j\ll \mu$.

I am not sure if this is correct, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have the absolute continuity in reverse in your proof.  To say $\mu_{j} \ll \mu$ means if $\mu(E) = 0$, then $\mu_{j}(E) = 0$.  In your proof, you showed the opposite.

Comment: Also, you need all the measures to be positive for the proposition to hold.

Comment: Other than dealing with absolute continuity, I don't see what this has to do with the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Proposition 3.11 - If $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ are measures on $(X,M)$, there is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_j\ll\mu$ for all $j$ - namely $\mu = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu_j$.

Proof - Suppose we have a sequence of (positive) measures $\{\mu_j\}_{1}^{n}$ on $(X,M)$. 
 Define $$\mu = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu_j$$ It is easy to see that $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,M)$.

Moreover, for any $E \in M$, if $\mu(E)=0$, then 
$$\sum_{1}^{n}\mu_j(E) = \mu(E)=0$$
So, for all $j$, $\mu_j(E)=0$. So, for all $j$, $\mu_j \ll \mu$.